# Tab space inconsistency in a txt file using PHP

Tags: php, text-files, indentation, spaces

I have generated this attached file uploaded here: https://files.fm/u/uqm4marg
This file was generated using PHP. \t was used to insert a tab space. It has worked find through out the entire file but for the tab space between INR0564 D and INR0564 C. This tab space only has one white space while other tab spaces have 4 like between 667722553331 and INR0564.

So the question is while \t was used to give a tab space between characters why is there different spacing at different places.

The below image is taken on sublime text which shows the different tab spaces mentioned above.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The [`tab` character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key#Tab_characters) does not insert spaces. It is a single character that is interpreted by the editor.

The [purpose of the tab character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key#History) is to help writing data in tabular format, i.e. in table format. Since the rows are already provided by the lines of text, the `tab` character helps creating columns.

The editors interpret the `tab` character as moving the cursor to the right not one position (as it happens with the `space` character) but until it reaches the next tabulator stop.

In computer software, the tabulator stops are usually set at each 8 or 4 columns. This means either columns `1`, `9`, `17` a.s.o. or `1`, `5`, `9`, `13` etc. In your picture (and from the description in your question) it seems the "size" of your tab you are using is `4` columns (this is the mostly used value nowadays).

Because the `tab` character sends the cursor to a fixed position, its perceived "size" is not fixed, it depends of the cursor column before the `tab` character.

In your image, the first column of data has 12 characters (it is displayed on columns `1-12` in the editor). Then, the `tab` character sends the cursor to the next tabulator that is on column `17`. The next value (`INR0564`, `7` characters) is displayed in columns `17-23`. The next `tab` character is "shorter", it covers only `1` column; it sends the cursor to column `25` where is displayed `D`. The next one makes the cursor jump to column `29` (`3` columns) where nothing is displayed. Then there is another `tab` that spans `4` characters until the next tabulator (in column `33`) where the `2.0SEp Salary` value starts.

The columns, the tabulators anb and your data are depicted below:

```
1   5   9   13  17  21  21  25  29  33 ...
v   v   v   v   v   v   v   v   v   v  ...
056665554531    INR0564 D       2.0Sep Salary
            .   |      .|.  |   |
            +-->|      >|+->+-->|
```

In the above drawing, a dot (`.`) marks the position of the cursor after each column of data and a pipe (`|`) marks its position after the `tab` character was displayed. The "arrows" on the last line depict how the cursor jumped over multiple columns because of the `tab` characters, to reach the next tabulator.

Comment: When I open this in sublime text or textmate or in notepad it shows me the same format, so I think it has nothing to do with the editors. Can we not tell PHP to make a consistent tabular space indentation of 4 spaces ?

Comment: Have you read my answer? Read it again. Then take a closer look to the image you posted. There are only 3 empty columns after `D` (for the first tab then another 4 columns for the second tab. And PHP is not involved in the way the editors display the tab character. If you want to always have 4 spaces between the columns then use 4 spaces and not tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Your editor is configured to advance the cursor to the next tab stop.  With a tab width configured to 4 characters, tab stops are at line offsets 0, 4, 8, a.s.o.  It should be understandable, that a horizontal tab on offset 11 will advance to offset 12, and not to 15 (11 + 4).  It's just not a fixed width, but must be seen in relation to fixed stops.

Answer (score 1):

Tabs Spaces has nothing to do with if you have given correct \t in code, It has generated correctly. The behaviour tab is differs with type of editor.

For Instance , If you use below code for generation

```
 $myfile = fopen(getcwd()."/newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open 
                  file!");
            $txt = "BATBALL88026613\n
                    667722553331\tINR0564D\tSeptember\t2.00Salary\n
                    051122334432\tINR0564C\tSeptember\t1.00Salary\n
                    056401112233\tINR0564C\tSeptember\t1.00Salary";
            fwrite($myfile, $txt);
            fclose($myfile);
```

And you try to open in NOTEPAD and NOTEPAD++ it will be different. That inconsistency will not be there in NOTEPAD++.

Comment: There is no inconsistency. Notepad puts tabulator marks at every `8` columns (the "size" of a `tab` character is `8` in Notepad), Notepad++ uses `4`, like most of the other editors nowadays.